# How to prove that $i_{k,\ k+1}$ it is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $i_{k,\ k+1}$: $H^k(\mathbb{T}^d) \to H^{k+1}(\mathbb{T}^d)$ a identy operator where $H^k(\mathbb{T}^d)$ it is Sobolev_space in toro $\mathbb{T}^d$. Prove that $i_{k,\ k+1}$ it is compact operator.

Comment: how take a sequence of compacts operators convergent to $i_{k, k+1}$?

Comment: You should provide more information. What are $H^k(\mathbb{T}^d)$? Are they Hardy spaces? What is $i_{k,k+1}$? Is it some kind of inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to use Fourier series.  This turns the Sobolev spaces into weighted $\ell^2$ spaces for which it is easy to demonstrate the compactness of the appropriate mappings.